# DirectoryIterator fails on Network Attached Storage

Tags: php, filesystems

This simplest of all iterators:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
 <?php
  $it = new DirectoryIterator("c:");

  foreach($it as $file) 
  {
    if (!$it->isDot()) 
    {
      echo $file . "\n";
    }
  }
 ?>
</head>
<body>
 Test of directory iterator
</html>
```

This works fine on my local C: drive but if I change it to my Network Attached Storage drive (Z:) it fails with:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message 'DirectoryIterator::__construct(z:,z:): The system cannot find the path specified. (code: 3)' in B:\public_html\test\test.php on line 8
>   ( ! ) UnexpectedValueException: DirectoryIterator::__construct(z:,z:): The system cannot find the path specified. (code: 3) in B:\public_html\test\test.php on line 8

In all other respects the NAS works fine.

LocalHost is an Apache WAMP with PHP 5

Comment: I edited your question just a little bit to clean up the formatting and update the wording. I added the `filesystems` tag simply to differentiate it from the many, many other PHP questions. Irrespective of the edit, it may be that the underlying library used by PHP can't handle NAS or other mapped drive locations. You may want to try using a network path instead (e.g., \\drivename). Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the error message you get:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message 'DirectoryIterator::__construct(z:,z:): The system cannot find the path specified. (code: 3)' in **B:**\public_html\test\test.php on line 8 ( ! ) UnexpectedValueException: DirectoryIterator::__construct(z:,z:): The system cannot find the path specified. (code: 3) in **B:**\public_html\test\test.php on line 8

So you have to change your `c:` to `B:`

Comment: Humm. I don't think that is the problem.

B: is where the code is being executed (its a SSD) but z: is the NAS that I am attempting to access

Comment: @SetiNet If you try to access: `z:` why do you write: `c:` ?!

Comment: @SetiNet Now you are writing complete nonsense! In your question you wrote that it doesn't work and now it works?!

Comment: Like I said. If I set up an Iterator on my C: or B: drive as in $it = new DirectoryIterator("c:"); it works fine.
When I set up an iterator on my NAS, which is drive Z: it fails.
I don't think I can be much clearer than that.

If you look at the error message it tells you (well me at least) that the constructor failed setting up on Z: